# Как итерироваться по всем элементам boost::multi_index, если его элемент имеет move-семантику?

Tags: c++, boost

И насколько вообще реально использование такого вот:

```
typedef boost::multi_index_container<foo, ...

struct foo {
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar; // requires move-semantic only
    foo() { bar = std::make_unique<Bar>(); }
    foo(foo&&) = default;
};
```

push_back успешно компилируется - просто push_back(std::move(...)).

Также компилируется поиск, если я не итерирую, а сразу передаю итератор, полученный из `find`, в функцию:

```
auto it = container.get<...>().find(...);
container.erase(it);
```

Но мне еще нужно пройтись по всем элементам контейнера. Делаю так:

```
for (auto it = container.begin(); auto it = container.end(); ++it) {
   some_foo(*it); // Например, another_container.push_back(*it) - чтобы добавить элемент в другой контейнер
}
```

И это не компилируется. Ни один из вариантов:

```
some_foo(std::move(*it))
some_foo(std::move(it))
some_foo(it)
some_foo(*it)
```

Оно хочет конструктор копирования вместо move конструктора...

Comment: Вы что хотите переместить элемент перед удалением из контейнера?

Comment: @Cerbo положить в другой контейнер, а будет ли удаление - не принципиально.

Comment: После перемещения обязательно должно быть удаление.

Comment: @Cerbo Ок. Хоть так. А то никакого кода нет рабочего.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, что Ваш код заработал и система «съела» и переместила элемент контейнера в функцию, что станет с контейнером? Перемещение это модифицирующая операция (в общем случае), а в multindex использует информацию из узлов, для построения дерева.

Да даже если бы не использовал и это был бы обычный вектор, нельзя просто взять и оставить элемент в непонятном состоянии в контейнере, если конечно этот контейнер тут же не удаляется. Просто находите нужный элемент, извлекайте его из контейнера (удаляйте), а затем уже перемещайте.